# Deploying multiple VM's with different number of disk each VM's need's

Tags: ansible

I have playbook for deploying multiple VM's with multiple disk it's working fine..
But when I deploying multiple VM's with different number of disk each VM's need's in this situation I tried condition's in playbook but it's not working as I expected..

for example below is requirements

APP : 2 disk

DB: 3 disk

I'm passing through disk variables from my inventory files..

look like below

APP guest_disk1='100' guest_disk2='200'

DB guest_disk1='100' guest_disk2='200' guest_disk3='300'

I modified my playbook with when condition like these

```
     vmware_guest:
       ....
       name: '{{ inventory_hostname }}'
       disk:
         - size_gb: '{{ guest_disk1 }}'
           type: thin
           datastore: '{{ datastore1 }}'
     when: '"APP or DB" in inventory_hostname'
         - size_gb: '{{ guest_disk2 }}'
           type: thin
           datastore: '{{ datastore1 }}'
     when: '"APP or DB" in inventory_hostname
         - size_gb: '{{ guest_disk3 }}'
           type: thin
           datastore: '{{ datastore1 }}'
     when: '"DB" in inventory_hostname'
```

When I ran the playbook got below error msg

ERROR! We were unable to read either as JSON nor YAML, these are the errors we got from each:
JSON: No JSON object could be decoded

Syntax Error while loading YAML.
did not find expected key

The error appears to be in '/opt/myagent/avi/ansible/ansible-deploy-vmware-vm2/roles/vm/tasks/main.yml': line 44, column 13, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

```
      when: '"APP or DB" in inventory_hostname'
        - size_gb: '{{ guest_disk2 }}'
        ^ here
```

We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes. Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:

```
with_items:
  - {{ foo }}
```

Should be written as:

```
with_items:
  - "{{ foo }}"
```

I tired this condition in disk task itself but it's still same error

```
     vmware_guest:
       ....
       name: '{{ inventory_hostname }}'
       disk:
         - size_gb: '{{ guest_disk1 }}'
           type: thin
           datastore: '{{ datastore1 }}'
       when: '"APP or DB" in inventory_hostname'
         - size_gb: '{{ guest_disk2 }}'
           type: thin
           datastore: '{{ datastore1 }}'
       when: '"APP or DB" in inventory_hostname'
         - size_gb: '{{ guest_disk3 }}'
           type: thin
           datastore: '{{ datastore1 }}'
       when: '"DB" in inventory_hostname'
```

When I comment out the when condition in playbook it's deploying DB only. not APP it's failed with undefined variables for guest_disk3 because of in my inventory I didn't defined any variables for guest_disk3 for APP..  (I need 2 disk only for APP )

Thanks for advance

Comment: I would create a helper `set_fact` task which would create a list of dicts (`dict = { 'name': 'xxx', 'type': 'xxx', 'datastore': 'xxx', 'size': XY}`), and use just one loop and refer to `item.name` etc... This way it would be more readable... And BTW... `with_xxx` syntax is obsolete.

Comment: @JiriB [`with_xxx` is not obsolete](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html) only recommended => `We added loop in Ansible 2.5. It is not yet a full replacement for with_<lookup>, but we recommend it for most use cases. We have not deprecated the use of with_<lookup> - that syntax will still be valid for the foreseeable future.`

Comment: Hello @JiriB, Thanks 

Actually I'm beginner level of ansible. I didn't use set_fact module yet at any 
 of playbook can u describe the syntax of set_fact based on this requirements

Comment: @Avi There are great examples on the Ansible docs as well: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/set_fact_module.html

Comment: Thanks @cjnash it's very useful..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is not a valid yaml/task/playbook sample. Moreover, your data structure is far from ideal to deal with this. Don't create independent vars, use lists. If you want to DRY and limit verbosity, you can apply override values to all disks if you always have the same options

All-in-one example inventory:

```yaml
all:
  vars:
    datastore1: someds
    disk_override_values:
      type: thin
      datastore: "{{ datastore1 }}"
    guest_disks: "{{ disk_sizes | map('combine', disk_override_values) | list }}"

  hosts:
    app:
      disks_sizes:
        - size: 100
        - size: 200
     db:
       disks_sizes:
        - size: 100
        - size: 200
        - size: 300
```

Example task (didn't test the vmware tasks, I don't have an infra for that)

```yaml
- name: create guest
  vmware_guest:
    name: '{{ inventory_hostname }}'
    disk: "{{ guest_disk }}"
  delegate_to: localhost
```

Comment: IMO there's OS disk and data disks for apps/dbs. I like your approach but I would add under `all:` add something like `os_disks` as list, then change `disk_sizes` under hosts to `data_disks` and I would add under task `vars` with `_disks: "{{ os_disks + data_disks }}"`. This way it would be more visible what's going on.

Comment: @JiriB This is a quickNdirty approach based on OP's info only. I didn't even read the examples in the module documentation and I wrote all this on-spot. As stated I do not have any vmware infra to test this and to validate the parameters. The idea is just to put OP on track.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Zeitounator Task is working fine

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html

Now I got set_fact syntax using in variables through my inventory file before I was passing the variables through my inventory file like ini format. now inventory is YAML format I can pass other variables also too..